# How is it possible to fit multiple data at the same time with curve_fit (scipy.optimize) or model.fit (lmfit)?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, lmfit

For a given time (*t*), I recorded simultaneously 4 values (*Imeas1, Imeas2, Imeas3, Imeas4*) that depends of the same parameters (*a,b*) but the model functions (*func1 func2 func3 func4*) are differents.
I defined a model function that returns an array of 4 values:

```
def func(t, a, b):
    Icalc1=func1(t,a,b)
    Icalc2=func2(t,a,b)
    Icalc3=func3(t,a,b)
    Icalc4=func4(t,a,b)
    return [Icalc1,Iclac2,Icalc3,Icalc4]
```

I measured this 4 values at 6 different time values :

```
xMeas = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
yMeas = np.array([
         [I1meas1,I1meas2,I1Meas3,I1Meas4],
         [I2meas1,I2meas2,I2Meas3,I2Meas4],
         [I3meas1,I3meas2,I3Meas3,I3Meas4],
         [I4meas1,I4meas2,I4Meas3,I4Meas4],
         [I5meas1,I5meas2,I5Meas3,I5Meas4],
         [I6meas1,I6meas2,I6Meas3,I6Meas4]])
```

`scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, xMeas, yMeas, vGuess)` does not work because yMeas must be an one dimensional array. But, I would like to fit the 4 measurements together because they are recorded at the same time.

Is it possible to do that with another scipy function or another library as lmfit ?
Thanks for answer.

Comment: Nope.  Just because they were measured together does not mean they have the same curve.  Just run the `curve_fit` four times.

Comment: @Tim Roberts. Thanks for answer. The curve are not the same but the parameters (a,b) are shared for the four signals. So, it is the same fitting.

Comment: You have four function.  It is four independent curve fittings.  That's just the way it is.

Comment: @Tim Roberts. Not sure to understand. If I perform **4** independent curve fittings, I will get **4** sets of parameters a and b. Right ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  If they are 4 independent functions, it has to be that way.  Right?  I may have gone off track.

Answer (score 1):

The model function should return a 1-d numpy array with all the values.

If your `Icalc1`, `Icalc2`, etc are numpy-arrays, use `numpy.concatenate()` to combine them into a single 1-D array:

```
 #
 return numpy.concatenate((Icalc1, Icalc2, Icalc3, Icalc4))
```

If `Icalc1`, etc are scalar values, just turn those into an array:

```
 #
 return numpy.array((Icalc1, Icalc2, Icalc3, Icalc4))
```

Comment: @M.Newville. How can I create a model (`my_model`) with 4 functions and after, run my_model.fit ? Is it possible to do define a model with a function that returns 4 expressions ?

Comment: @M. Newville. I tried but it does not work. *TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''*. Do you want I open an new question with the details ?

Comment: @Stef1611 the code you posted does not have a `my_model` defined or use `np.isinfinite`.   You must provide a minimal working example (looking that up if needed) of actual code.